# glm::value_ptr(glm::vec1{})

Tags: glm

El siguiente código genera un error de compilación usando la librería GLM 0.9.9.8

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/vec1.hpp>

void main(){
  glm::value_ptr(glm::vec1{1.0f});
}
```

Al parecer no se puede usar la función `glm::value_ptr()` con un `glm::vec1`.
¿Por ninguna razón en particular?